# Unit Testing - Passing enum as method parameters in Test Class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a class called Game. I am wondering what is best practice in this situation to pass the enums in the Game class to the Test class as parameters in a method

Game class has the following:

```
public enum Result
{
  Zero,
  One,
  etc...
}

public int ResultCount(Result result)
{
  switch(result)
  {
    case Result.Zero
         return 0;
    case Result.One
         retun 1;
    etc...
  }
}

public void CurrentResult(Result hometeam, Result awayteam)
{
  setHomeTeamGoals(hometeam);
  setAwayTeamGoals(awayteam);
}
```

I then have a unit test class where I want to set the result in the setup

```
 [TestFixture]
    public class Result_is_1_1
    {
        private Game _game;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _game = new Game();
            _game.CurrentResult(Result.One, Result.One);
        }
```

It works when I use the following

```
using static unitTest.Game;
```

But I am unsure if this is bad practice/ quick fix etc.

What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the use of `using static`? If so, what led you to use that in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question because you haven't provided complete/working code. But I'm guessing that you defined `Result` as a nested enum inside the `Game` class, and that is causing some confusion.

So I assume your `Game` class looks like this:

```cs
public class Game
{
    public enum Result
    {
        Zero,
        One,
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```

Assuming that's the case, the full name of your enum is `Game.Result`, because `Result` is defined within `Game`.

So when you want to reference the `Result` enum from your unit test (or from any other class, for that matter), you have two options.

Option 1, reference `Game.Result` (no `using static` required):

```cs
_game.CurrentResult(Game.Result.One, Game.Result.One);
```

Option 2, use a `using static` statement like you've done:

```cs
using static unitTest.Game;
// ...
_game.CurrentResult(Result.One, Result.One);
```

(Bonus third option, you could define the `Result` enum outside the `Game` class. Then you don't need to worry about option 1 or 2.)

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, then it's not a bad testing practice. In fact, it doesn't have anything to do with testing at all. It's just a language feature. Personally, I prefer using the full name `Game.Result`, rather than using the `using static` statement.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using static for your class under test is usually a smell indicating bad test design. If you want to have your tests be independent, as is the usual practice for unit testing, create a new Game for each test by instantiating it in your SetUp method - just as you are now doing.

If you want to perform multiple steps in sequence on the same game, the usual approach is to do those steps within the test itself.

If you want each of your test methods to actually **be** a step that is performed in a certain order, you are getting away from what's generally considered to be **unit** testing and doing a different type of test. You are also getting away from what NUnit is best at.

**However**, if you really want to, you can create your Game in a `[OneTimeSetUp]` method and order all your tests with the `OrderAttribute` in order to run them in sequence. This makes your tests somewhat fragile because each one depends on all the tests that ran before it.